# an idiom for a solution that "triumphs all others"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom which in my mind is "the golden egg", but apparently I just made that up. An idiom for a solution that "triumphs all others"

Comment: In what context would you like to use this?  (It can make a difference in the answers you get)

Comment: "takes the cake", "win's the title", "claims the prize" are a few.. there are other ways of saying each and many more similar ones.

Comment: blue-ribbon solution

Comment: Aren't you thinking of "*trumps* all others"?  I've never heard "triumphs all others", and I wouldn't know what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: "triumphs all others" should be "triumphs *over* all others"

Comment: [better mousetrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_a_better_mousetrap,_and_the_world_will_beat_a_path_to_your_door)  as in "Build a better mousetrap and the world will beat a path to your door."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're thinking of the idiom [***silver bullet***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silver%20bullet). From Merriam-Webster:

> something that acts as a magical weapon; especially :  one that instantly solves a long-standing problem

So if you are considering a lot of different partial solutions to a problem, the solution that works better than all of them put together would be described as a *silver bullet*.

M-W doesn't include an etymology for the idiom, but I assume it has something to do with silver bullets being the legendary solution to one's werewolf problem (and sometimes other folkloric baddies).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "the holy grail" as an idiom for the greatest of all.

> ***[grail](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/grail)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. (in medieval legend) the cup or platter used by Jesus at the Last Supper, and in which Joseph of Arimathea received Christ's blood at the Cross. Quests for it undertaken by medieval knights are described in versions of the Arthurian legends written from the early 13th century onward.
> 2. A thing that is being earnestly pursued or sought after.
>       *‘profit has become the holy grail’*